# How to detect memory warnings in iOS App Extension

Tags: ios, didreceivememorywarning, ios-extensions, networkextension

I'm writing an iOS extension that extends `NEPacketTunnelProvider` in the NetworkExtension framework released in iOS 9.  I'm running into a situation where iOS is killing the extension once hits 6MB of memory used.

In a regular iOS app,  there are two ways to detect memory warnings and do something about it.  Either via `[UIApplicationDelegate applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication*)app]` or `[UIViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning]`

Is there a similar way to detect memory warnings within an extension?  I've searched up and down the iOS extension documentation but have come up empty thus far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not very familiar with the extensions API, however my basic hunch says that you can register any of your object as observers of [`UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification) from within that class:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification,
  object: nil, queue: .mainQueue()) { notification in
    print("Memory warning received")
}
```

Comment: @Grant Limberg @ozgur I tried this with a NotificationServiceExtension and the block is never fired. Even passing in a new `NSOperationQueue` so the block an fire on it's own thread.

Comment: I don't know why answer is marked as correct, this is not! We have no access to "UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification" from the extension.

Comment: It doesnt work;) Wy it is correct?

Answer (score 5):

ozgur's answer does not work. UIApplicationDidReceiveMemeoryWarningNotification is a UIKit event and I haven't found a way to get access to that from an extension. The way to go is the last of [these options](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/improving_your_app_s_performance/reducing_your_app_s_memory_use/responding_to_low-memory_warnings): DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_MEMORYPRESSURE.

I've used the following code (Swift) in a Broadcast Upload Extension and have confirmed with breakpoints that it is called during a memory event right before the extension conks out.

```
let source = DispatchSource.makeMemoryPressureSource(eventMask: .all, queue: nil)

let q = DispatchQueue.init(label: "test")
q.async {
    source.setEventHandler {
        let event:DispatchSource.MemoryPressureEvent  = source.mask
        print(event)
        switch event {
        case DispatchSource.MemoryPressureEvent.normal:
            print("normal")
        case DispatchSource.MemoryPressureEvent.warning:
            print("warning")
        case DispatchSource.MemoryPressureEvent.critical:
            print("critical")
        default:
            break
        }
        
    }
    source.resume()
}
```